# How can i go to my current location in Mapboxgl?

Tags: geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I want to navigate to users current location in the map. I am working with Mapboxgl, Ionic3 and Angular4.

I used the  following code `map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl());`

This works fine in development `(ie web browser)` but my target is a mobile application. My app will be used in both `android and ios mobiles`.

I guess it supports click event in web browser not in mobiles. It may work if I write touch event for this.

I prefer to write the custom code for this navigation. I mean place some icon and write the same functionality instead of `mapboxgl.GeolocateControl()`

Answer (score 0):

As MapBox-gl is touch-enabled, I would be surprised if the the GeolocateControl would not support touch events.

The GeolocateControl should work in Ionic on both Android and iOS. Make sure you tell your app to request permissions for geolocation

Comment: You are right. It is not related to touch event. Its related to permission